# Transferring data from one raster to another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, population

I have 2 raster layers. The first is a mobile signal coverage raster with 0 and 1 values. The second is a population raster with value from 0.89 to 236. I want to transfer the population layer to the mobile signal coverage raster. I am using the raster calculation function in QGIS. Also, the extent that I use is the mobile signal extent. The calculation I am using is:

```
(“mobilesignal@1” >= 0) * “population@1"
```

But the result is not correct and the population numbers on the mobile signal raster are way too low.

Can anyone help me with the correct calculation?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly (you want to transfer population layer values to mobile signal raster only where its value is 1 ?)

> “mobilesignal@1” * “population@1"

should work.

Then you can use Raster > Conversion > Translate if you want to replace 0s with no data / null.

Comment: That is exactly right. The population layer has values up until 236 and the mobile signal layer is 0 or 1. But when I do the “mobilesignal@1” * “population@1" (using mobile signal as the extent), only some of the population data is transferred to the new raster file. I can't work out why.

Comment: Do the rasters have the same resolution and are the pixels aligned? If they're not then the calculation may do a proportional area calculation rather than just a straight pixel*pixel calc?